# Change text upon toggle div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How can I get the toggle to say Less Information when clicked? I tried using the::after prompt in css but couldn't get it working. I also want to style the 'Less Information' in css. Maybe I should make it call upon a class?

```
<div class="toggle">More Information</div>

$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".content").hide();

  $(".toggle").on("click", function(e){   
      $(this).next('.content').slideToggle(200); 

    });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) to replace the text inside the `div`.

**Try this:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".content").hide();
  $(".toggle").on("click", function(){   
      $(this).next('.content').slideToggle(200);
      $(this).text($(this).text() == 'More Information' ? 'Less Information' : 'More Information');
    });
});
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ouc2z7wj/)**

**UPDATE**

You could also use `:visible` to check if content is visible and change text accordingly.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".content").hide();
    $(".toggle").on("click", function () {
        var txt = $(".content").is(':visible') ? 'More Information' : 'Less Information';
        $(".toggle").text(txt);
        $(this).next('.content').slideToggle(200);
    });
});
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ouc2z7wj/2/)**

Comment: thanks! but how would I style that text to say a different color?

Comment: Which text... the one in `.content` or the `Less Information`?

Comment: Use `toggleClass()` if you want just `Less Information` to change text. Check this http://jsfiddle.net/ouc2z7wj/3/

Comment: I just noticed if you have multiple of the toggles, and you press it, it changes the text on all of them. How can I get it to just replace the text on the actively clicked one?

Answer (score 1):

Could do like this: **Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/f1dmhf0d/

- API : `.prev` - http://api.jquery.com/prev/
- or could look into this: http://api.jquery.com/next-siblings-selector/

*Detail* safely assuming your content is above "more info" you can traverse through the dom and use `:visible` flag aa=ccordingly to change the text using `.text`

Hope rest fits your need. `:)`

**code**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".content").hide();

    $(".toggle").on("click", function (e) {

        var $this = $(this).prev('.content');
        var $text = $(this);
        $this.slideToggle('slow', function () {
            if ($(this).is(':visible')) {
                $text.text('less info');
            } else {
                $text.text('more info');
            }
        });

    });
});
```